# how to record a draggable item that is shuffled into place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

The setup. In Edge Animate

5 items are on the stage and are placed at random y position.

```
    var logs1 = ['C1L1','C1L2','C1L3','C1L4','C1L5'];
    var posY = [196,236,276,316,356];
```

I use a function to shuffle the items in array
shuffle(poxY);

5 droppables are on the stage position 1,2,3,4,5

I use 2 drop events for the draggables.
1- one to swap the items.
2- one to record when the dragged item overlaps the correct draggable

Example: 
if I drag item1 over item2, they swap places
if 1 is dropped at the current droppable, the drop event records it.

However if by any chance item 2 is also swapped to the correct position, it is not recorded.

How can I make this happen?

```
var logs1 = ['C1L1','C1L2','C1L3','C1L4','C1L5'];
var posY = [196,236,276,316,356];

for(j = 0; j < logs1.length; j++){
    sym.$(logs1[j]).addClass('logs1'+j);
    sym.$('.logs1'+j).draggable({
        zIndex: 1000,
        axis: "y",
        revert: function(obj){
            if(obj===false){                    
                sym.getSymbol("beaver").stop("stop3");      
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        },
        start: function(event, ui) {
            sym.$("water").show();
            startPos = $(this).offset().top;
            //waterRisingLoop.pause();
            sym.getSymbol("beaver").stop("stop1");
        }
    });
    // swap the logs
    sym.$('.logs1'+j).droppable({
        drop: function(ui,event){
            $(this).css({'top': startPos});         
        }
    }); 
    // accept the log   
    sym.$(droppable[j]).droppable({
        accept: ".logs1"+j,
        drop: dropEvent         
    });
} // end for loop

k = 0;
function dropEvent(event, ui){
    logDropFX.play();
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
   $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'center', at: 'middle'}); 
    waterRisingLoop.play();     
    sym.getSymbol("beaver").stop("stop2");
    k++;
    sym.$("marker").animate({'top':400-( 50 * k)},1000);
    var markerPos = sym.$("marker").offset().top;
    console.log("marker level: " + waterPos);   
    if(markerPos < 250 && k == 5 ){         
        clearInterval(timer);
        setTimeout(function() {
               sym.$('levelScreen').animate({"top":0,'z-index':99999},1000);
                sym.$("level").attr('src', 'images/level1Complete.png');
                sym.$(".set1").hide();
                levelUpFX.play();
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can add `fiddle` we can help you better.

Comment: Unfortunately fiddle does not deal with Edge Animate code as far as I know.